# NLTK Text Categorization confidence Naive Bayes

Tags: nltk

I've developed a text categorization script very similar to the example in Chapter 6 of the nltk book. I want to categorize customer responses into buckets such as 'ordering', 'billing', etc.

I have responses that I labeled for use as a training set. For simplicity, let me give just two examples of the training data:

'Ordering new products is easy' : 'ordering'

'My bill was incorrect' : 'billing'

After training the NB classifier, let's say I classified the following document: 'Service in this area stinks'.

The classifier will give it a label, either ordering or billing, although it has no words that appeared in the training data for either, so I need to know whether or not to accept the result if that makes sense.

I have looked at the _proba_dict and thought I would be able to use that to determine if it was a good match or not, but I haven't really found a reliable way to use it. For example, sometimes it will show really low numbers for both labels, which is what you would expect in this example, but other times it would not.

Taking it a step further, we possibly would want to assign multiple labels to a single document. Consider: 'Ordering was easy but billing was a nightmare'. In this scenario, I may want to flag it as both ordering and billing. Again, I thought I could use the probabilities to determine if more than one label is appropriate, but I'm still not seeing how to do that.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to add a third category NONE, that stands for not billing nor ordering and put some sentences on this class. Then you'll have a three class problem and your system will be able to decide if a document is not about billing nor ordering.

If you want to allow multilabels, a first approach can be to use the three class classifier and put thresholds on the probabilities of billing and ordering. However, that is not anywhere near optimal.

If you want to do true multi-label prediction you have an article that describes a full NLP pipeline [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-label-text-classification-with-scikit-learn-30714b7819c5)

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at this!